# Download xcode from phone

Tags: android, iphone, xcode, download

Is it possible to download my apps code from my IPhone 5s and Android. My developer in India disappeared and I am trying desperately to get a hold of her. I dont know if there is a holiday over there or if she is sick.

Anyhow my app is finished on both platforms and all that needs to be done is transfer the database to Amazon and the respective stores.

Is there any way to rescue this code on my phones?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you want to reverse engineer or extract the code from a copy of the app installed on your phone.

It's called App Decompiling and while in theory, it's possible to do it, it won't "just work" as easy as copy & paste. Especially taken you've got 2 different platforms to decompile from.

On iOS, for example, the apps are protected by its DRM https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FairPlay technology which splits the app into segments and encrypts each of them with a separate key. To attempt to decompile the app, you'll need to jailbreak https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking your device, which immediately voids all of its warranties. Even then, it's not certain you'll be able to extract enough of the code to rebuild the app.

On Android, it's slightly easier, but would still not exactly grant you the Java source code.

Bottom line, it's extremely difficult, unreliable, quite expensive (*if not performed by yourself*) and probably not worth it in your case.

Comment: I dont mind jailbreaking my IPhone 5s LOL. I do have some apk files. Is this all I need for the Android code? Would my developer account have the code anywhere or itunes connect?